# Salesforce backup questions

Tags: apex, community

Would like to know if any one used a backup tool to backup the Salesforce data, how often do you take full backup?

Answer (score 1):

There's no "one-size fits all" answer to this question. It depends on the backup solution you've chosen. Imagine you have a system that has five minute replication windows and fully automated restoration. You might choose to just use the default "monthly export" feature that Salesforce has. On the other hand, you might just have a small amount of data, so you use an automated tool to make a nightly backup. Alternatively, you might be at an organization that has legal requirements or CTO (Chief Technology Officer) requirements that all data must be backed up with a certain frequency. The full backup should be supplemented with other fail-safes in case a disaster occurs.